# SQL query on two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
SELECT  p.autor, p.tresc, p.data, u.id
FROM   pages_com p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN users u on p.autor = u.username
WHERE p.wpis = ?
ORDER BY p.id DESC
```

My error is:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '? ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 0, 30' at line 4

My code:

```
$query = "SELECT  p.autor, p.tresc, p.data, u.id
FROM   pages_com p
       LEFT OUTER JOIN users u on p.autor = u.username
WHERE p.wpis = ?
ORDER BY p.id DESC";
                $statement = $databaseConnection->prepare($query);
                $statement->bind_param('s', $id);
```

Error in fucntion bind_param:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in
>   /home/p503373/public_html/v2/page.php on line 81

Comment: `$statement = $databaseConnection->prepare($query);` < that failed and you're not trapping errors, check `$databaseConnection`

Comment: @ccKep MySQL has of course left outer join

Comment: It looks like `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is supported by MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: I know, I was a bit confused - deleted the comment literally 2 secs after posting ;-)

Comment: What's the problem ? Can you provide a solution to this problem? In another file such application worked and not here.